# npm install - ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to `npm install` but getting this error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: webapp@21.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@9.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"9.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cdk@"8.2.3" from @angular/material@8.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   @angular/material@"8.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 9):

I updated node.js to the latest recommended LTS version which is currently version 14. This is what is causing the problem.

I tried using `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`, but this didn't work.

**The solution is to downgrade the node version to 12.**

Here is a copy/paste solution to fix. Copy all of this code and paste in the terminal at the root of your project. (Where your `package.json` file that you are trying to install is.)

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -rfv node_modules
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
nvm install 12
nvm use 12
npm i
```

What is happening here?

1. Remove the `package-lock.json` file
2. Remove the `node_modules` directory (`-rfv` = recursive, force, verbose)
3. Install `nvm` (Node Version Manager)
4. Configure `nvm`
5. Load `nvm`
6. Use `nvm` to install node v12
7. Tell this project to use node v12
8. Use `npm` to install the packages

Answer (score 8):

try `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` . This worked for me. But first make sure you delete your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`.

Comment: Excellent, @Franklin Ukaegbu!
I combined this with the two last suggestion from Codo Creed.

Answer (score 5):

```js
npm i package-name -f
```

If above command does not solve the error then use below both commands in terminal :

```js
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 2):

you have dependency conflicts.ignore it and install npm packages.try this:

```
npm install YourPackage --force
```

or

```
npm install YourPackage --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be created due to cache which has its own dependencies for the root user.

This will change to edit permissions for the npm cache folder.

```
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/"username"/.npm"
```

Now remove cache

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
```