# I am trying to install spline in my react project but when do i run script (npm i react-spline) it show many error

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, npm-install, spline

> 1. PS D:\program files\tailwind css\splinewithreact> npm i react-spline
> 2. npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> 3. npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> 4. npm ERR!
> 5. npm ERR! While resolving: splinewithreact@0.1.0
> 6. npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
> 7. npm ERR! node_modules/react
> 8. npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
> 9. npm ERR!
> 10. npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> 11. npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-spline@1.2.1
> 12. npm ERR! node_modules/react-spline
> 13. npm ERR!   react-spline@"*" from the root project
> 14. npm ERR!
> 15. npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> 16. npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> 17. npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
>     resolution.
> 18. npm ERR!
> 19. npm ERR! See
>     C:\Users\mkcor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a
>     full report.
> 20. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> 21. npm ERR!
>     C:\Users\mkcor\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-11T11_09_21_296Z-debug-0.log

**What should i need to change i could not understand please help me **

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install - ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67710630/npm-install-eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree)

Answer (score 2):

try
npm install @splinetool/react-spline @splinetool/runtime
in terminal

Answer (score 1):

run `npm install @splinetool/react-spline @splinetool/runtime --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Try "yarn add" instead of "npm install"

Cheers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).